# Is there iterative eigen decomposition method?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we know the eigen decomposition results of a real symmetric matrix $K_n = U * S * U'$, where $K_n$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix, $U$ is unitary matrix ($ U' * U = U * U' = I_n$) and $S$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now the goal is to decompose $K_{n+1}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  K_n & x \\
  x^T & z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is will the eigen decomposition result of $K_n$ be helpful in computing eigen values and eigen vectors of $K_{n+1}$?

Comment: It might be depending on what you know about $x$. Consider cofactor expansion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: So, just to be clear: $S$ is supposed to be diagonal, right?

Comment: And $U$ is meant to be orthogonal?  It would be nice if you had provided a bit more detail when asking the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you're right, and these information are reflected int he original question. Thanks.

Comment: @snarski I understand the determinant of $K_{n+1}$ can be easily calculated using Laplace expansion. But I cannot see its connection to the calculation of eigen vectors and eigen values. Please tell more about your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Define 
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
U & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We note that $P$ is an orthogonal matrix (since $U$ is orthogonal), and that 
$$
P'K_{n+1}P =
\begin{bmatrix}
S & U'x\\
x'U & z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You'll find that this (generally) is a much easier matrix to work with.

In fact, what I have shown here is a helpful first step in proving the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem).

---

So, following the above procedure, we now have a matrix

$$
A = P'K_{n+1}P =
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1&& & \\
&\ddots& &y\\
&&\lambda_n & \\
&y^T & & z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Once we have $A = VDV'$ for some diagonal $D$ and unitary $V$, we'll be able to say
$$
D = V'AV = V'P'K_{n+1}PV\implies K_{n+1} = (PV)D(PV)'
$$
which means that our task is to find the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$.  We find
$$
\det(tI - A) =
(t-z)\prod_{k=1}^n (t-\lambda_k) -{y_n}^2 \prod_{k\neq n}^n (t-\lambda_k) 
+ {y_{n-1}}^2\prod_{k\neq (n-1)}^n (t-\lambda_k) - \cdots
$$
I'm not quite sure where it would go from there...

Comment: after obtain $P'K_{n+1}P$, how can I continue to calculate eigen values and eigen vectors? I don't understand how to use the Cauchy interlacing theorem. Can you provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: The Cauchy interlacing theorem doesn't actually tell you what exactly the eigenvectors are.  It is, however, a useful fact about symmetric matrices. I'll put up a more detailed explanation about how to use this form to make computation easier if I have enough time this week

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess we stuck at the same place...

Comment: To come up with something useful, I suppose you'd have to look at how eigenvalues are actually computed (which is not necessarily be solving the associated polynomial).  Once you have the eigenvalues though, it will always be easy to row reduce the necessary matrix

Comment: Totally agree with you that more knowledge about eigenvalue computation is needed. I am looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm , it may practically work, although I don't know why it works.

Comment: Maybe there's an easy way to tridiagonalize this matrix with householder matrices